# I was prematurely awarded an association bonus

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I just received a +100 reputation bonus; according to the banner at the top of the page, it was because my associated English Usage account had reached 200 reputation points.  But I had only created the English Usage account a few minutes before, and it was (and still is) at 1 reputation, not 200.

Either the message is incorrectly describing the reason for the bonus, or the bonus was awarded prematurely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So there were 2 bugs here:

- The association bonus was correctly awarded on math, but with the wrong message.
- The association bonus wasn't granted on creation of the English user as it should have been.

Both of these are fixed in a build going out now, and I've backfilled bonuses for users affected.  Thanks for the heads up, looking at your data specifically helped me track this down.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad I could be of service.

Comment: @Nick: can you comment on [this "bug"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/why-was-i-awarded-an-association-bonus)?